# How to refresh list after changes with LazyAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, adapter, lazylist

I'm using LazyList for custom ListView and I need to refresh the list after the user changed it, in this case, add item as favorite.

I've tried to use:

```
     list.invalidate();
    ((BaseAdapter) list.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and

```
         list.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

but it doesn't seems to work on LazyList.

This is small part from my code :

```
        ListView list;
        LazyAdapter adapter; 

        //set the custom list adapter
        adapter = new LazyAdapter(this, fileString, null, movieNameString,
        mId, DataBaseSize,myScore,year4list,cast4list,favArray,bellArray);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        @Override
        public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        final AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

      switch (item.getItemId()) {
              case R.id.context_fav:

              //here theres non- importent code that makes favorite 
              pops when user click on it

         list.invalidate();
        ((BaseAdapter) list.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

For some reason, the list isn't updated; only when I use Intent and reenter the activity, the list is updated. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When you call notifyDataSetChange it will update the list , but it will get all values form         fileString and movieNameString , so you must update them before calling notifyDataSetChange.Otherwise you will find no change.